# What is the best way to accurately translate slang?

Tags: online-resources, translation, machine-translation, multilingualism, slang

It may not even be accurate to call it "slang"...
I am working on a filtering system that blocks pornography.
I have a set of key words and phrases in English. Essentially, I would like to have the equivalent of these words and phrases in various languages.  I considered trying to use Google Translate but was unsure how accurate it would be on the wide range of slang naughty words and phrases I have.
I thought about posting it as a job on Elance but I am unsure if someone on there will be able to do significantly better than I could using the right slang translator.

Thoughts?  Ideas?  Web site links?

Comment: Uhm I'm not sure this is strictly related to us...

Comment: You just want to be able to swear at taxi drivers, don't you!

Comment: @user548971, could you adjust the subject to better reflect what you're asking for?

Comment: Sorry, It's pretty obvious I'm not a linguist, huh?  What would you suggest?  "How to translate words for blocking porngraphy?"

Comment: Maybe "What is the best way to accurately translate NSFW-related slang?"

Comment: What exactly is your goal, to find the corresponding SFW term(/s) which maximize relevant search engine hits on your intended term, in each target language? Do you allow e.g. pronstar, p0rnstar? Conversely, translating obscene terms into artistically creative SFW terms would be like 'Beavis and Butthead'. (These will of course be no use for searching on.)

Answer (score 8):

I think you might be going at this the wrong way. Naughty words are naughty because they are used in a naughty manner, not because of what they actually mean, or used to mean. If we look at general swearwords, where they're taken from depends very much on culture. Where I am from, the bad, native swearwords are religious in theme: satan, hell, damn you etc. Swearwords realted to  bodily functions and sex are much rarer, many borrowed from English actually. In Brussels, some use the word "architect" as a swearword. Considering some of the architecture there and the history of how those buildings came about, that is very understandable. Due to some of the architecture that have turned up where I live, I've started using "architect" as a swearword myself.

What I think you are looking for is *euphemisms*, inoffensive words being used as stand-ins for offensive words. Euphemisms is a rich source of new naughty words, as the offensive meaning "rubs off", and then the euphemism needs a euphemism of its own. You'd need some way of discovering words that mean soft, words for anything that resembles a stick, and words for temperatures above normal at least, but this is fascinatingly unpredictable really.

The simplest would probably be to find porn-sites in various languages, sort them on language, get the text-content and use that to train a learning spam-filter. (You'll need text from non-porn sites too). Then see if you can pick out words or preferrably several word-pairs or word-triplets from that that are good indicators of "porniness".

And now for the obligatory reference in this case ;)

Quang Phúc Ðông: "[English sentences without overt grammatical subject](http://douglemoine.com/english-sentences-without-overt-grammatical-subjects/)", South Hanoi Institute of Technology, Hanoi, 1967

Comment: Thanks for this feedback.  I like the idea of finding a sampling of porn sites in each language and analyzing the key words.  I bet that would be more effective than trying to translate them.